# How to redirect based on url paramater

Tags: php, forms, redirect, get

I have a form on my website Where users can specify if they'd like a monthly or annual subscription (it's a radio option). This form gets sumbitted to my CRM system, which redirects the user to `www.site.com/is_to_pp.php?payment=Monthly&Address1=blah` (and other url variables).

Depending on whether `?payment=Monthly` or `?payment=Annual` I want to redirect them to a different paypal subscription page. I also want to pass the other variables to paypal to prepopulate the address fields.

I.e. the user fills out one form on our site, specifying how they'd like to pay, they are added to our crm system, and then redirected to the appropriate PayPal Page.

Does anyone have an idea of how to structure the `is_to_pp.php` file to handle this?

Any help/guidance is appreciated

Thanks

Charlie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
<?php
if ($_GET["payment"] == "Monthly") {
    header( 'Location: http://www.pageyouwant.com' );
    header("Location: paypalpage.com?payment=".$_GET['payment']."&address=".$_GET['address']);
} else {
    header("Location: paypalpage.com?payment=".$_GET['payment']."&address=".$_GET['address']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi @icanc, yes this is the sort of thing I need, but I need to also pass other get variables...

header( 'Location: http:www.pageyouwant.com?address1=$_GET["address1"]&address2=$_GET["address2"]' )

Comment: @CharlieWalker: You could pass the variables the same way.  I made the edit.

Comment: thank you so much for your quick answer - I knew it would be something simple! All working